# JTable from Resultset not scrolling vertically

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, tablemodel

I'm having trouble with a JTable component for more than a week now.  Hope you can point me in the right direction.

Inside a JInternalFrame form, I have a JTable created like so (Inside the auto-generated code from NetBeans):

```
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tblData = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jScrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    jScrollPane1.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(468, 167));
    jScrollPane1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(468, 167));
    jScrollPane1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(453, 167));

    tblData.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    tblData.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {

        },
        new String [] {
            "ID Empresa", "Código Empresa", "Nombre de la Empresa"
        }
    ));
    tblData.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    tblData.setIntercellSpacing(new java.awt.Dimension(5, 5));
    tblData.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(300, 100));
    tblData.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(300, 100));
    tblData.setName(""); // NOI18N
    tblData.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(300, 100));
    tblData.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tblData);
```

The table `tblData` is populated from a ResultSet that loads correctly (data has been verified via System.out.println()).  Now, the thing is that once the data has been retrieved, a function is called to "refresh" the table as follows:

```
private void prepareTable(boolean isEmpty) {
    String[] colHeadings = {"ID Empresa","Código Empresa","Nombre de la Empresa"};

    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
  tblData.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(tblData.getPreferredSize());

    try {
        if (isEmpty) {
            model.setColumnIdentifiers(colHeadings);
            tblData.setModel(model);
        } else {
            Verbo.rs.beforeFirst();

            tblData.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(Verbo.rs));
        }
    } catch (SQLException se) {

    }
    ((DefaultTableModel) tblData.getModel()).fireTableStructureChanged();

}
```

Thing is that, although the rows are retrieved and loaded to the table model, the vertical scroll bar for the table does not work even though it is shown, and therefore just the first records are shown.

Is there anything visible wrong with what I'm doing?  Please help me for I have searched and all answers here and in other sites have not been useful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should handle the exception. Maybe it will give you information about what's going on.

Comment: Thank you @YassinHajaj for the comment, I have added a general Exception, but nothing is thrown.  Apparently no error occurs.

Comment: Please post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Don't use tblData.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(tblData.getPreferredSize()); or ((DefaultTableModel) tblData.getModel()).fireTableStructureChanged()

Comment: Don't use setPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize, it's going to seriously screw with you

Comment: 1) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, using `setPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize` is going to cause you issues, you should also be careful using `setPreferredScrollableViewportSize` and should never use the component's `preferredSize` as this will make the scroll pane want to be the same size as the component.

You could also have a look at [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Answer (score 0):

I know that perhaps this is not the "best" solution, but out of despair I tried it and it worked:

- Simply I deleted the jTable and jScrollPane components from the form, and re-created them only this time I did not change anything but the size of the controls to fit my needs; no other option tampered with.

And this time it worked just as expected.